# AlertDialog on Android App Startup

Tags: android

I'm trying to make this dialog box run when the user has first downloaded the app and then never show again.

Here is my code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("key", true);

    if (isFirstStart) {
        //Line 39 is next
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Sample Title")
        .setMessage("Sample Message")
        .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
        })
        .show();

            SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();
            e.putBoolean("key", false);
            e.commit();
        }

    }
});

t.start();
```

This code is in an onCreate method inside a FragmentActivity. Specifically one that has three scroll tabs.

I am getting the following RunTimeError:

```
03-13 16:54:02.803    6759-6784/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7125
    Process: com.hidden.hidden, PID: 6759
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
            at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:109)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:931)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:950)
            at com.hidden.hidden.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:39)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Note: Package name is hidden for security.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Eliminate the `Thread` and put this code directly in your `onCreate()` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you put the code inside a thread?, if you put the alert outside the thread it should run fine, if its a must to use a thread show the alert dialog inside "runOnUiThread"

Comment: Works fine now. That was a bone head mistake on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `alertdialog` in your `onCreate()` method and using:

```
if (isFirstStart) {
    dialog.show()
}
```

Comment: Works fine now. That was a bone head mistake on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's seem like you're trying to change the UI from outside of the main thread.
Put your AlertDialog code outside of your new thread object and it should run normally.